# JEST Skipping Tests when Coverage Option Used

Tags: lwc-jest

I can run an individual JEST test successfully for this component:

```
    PS C:\Users\Dave2\Documents\Visual Studio Code\TMS> npm run test:unit dispatchConsoleCalendarCell.test.js

> tms@1.0.0 test:unit
> sfdx-lwc-jest "dispatchConsoleCalendarCell.test.js"

 PASS  force-app/main/default/lwc/dispatchConsoleCalendarCell/__tests__/dispatchConsoleCalendarCell.test.js
  c-dispatch-console-calendar-cell
    √ pto calendar cell (49 ms)
    √ preferred location calendar cell (12 ms)
    √ unassigned load calendar cell (31 ms)
    √ dispatched relay load calendar cell (32 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.239 s
Ran all test suites matching /dispatchConsoleCalendarCell.test.js/i.
```

But when I run it in coverage mode it does not show up:

```
npm run test:unit:coverage
```

**dispatchConsoleCalendarCell** is not shown in the coverage list.  Many are missing here.  They all used to be listed until a recent update of sfdx:

```
customerShipmentTrackingProgressIndicator     |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  customerShipmentTrackingProgressIndicator.js |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 | 4-24                                                                                                                           
 dispatchConsole                               |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsole.js                           |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 4-1004                                                                                                                         
 dispatchConsoleAssignments                    |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsoleAssignments.js                |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 4-340                                                                                                                          
 dispatchConsoleDataTable                      |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsoleDataTable.js                  |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 4-7                                                                                                                            
 dispatchConsoleDriverFilter                   |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsoleDriverFilter.js               |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 4-447                                                                                                                          
 dispatchConsoleFleetAssignment                |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsoleFleetAssignment.js            |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 4-767                                                                                                                          
 dispatchConsoleLoadFilter                     |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  dispatchConsoleLoadFilter.js                 |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 4-457                                                                                                                          
 driverLocation                                |     100 |    66.67 |     100 |     100 |                                                                                                                                
  driverLocation.js                            |     100 |    66.67 |     100 |     100 | 69-70                                                                                                                          
 freightQuoteAssistant                         |   37.93 |    18.18 |   26.67 |   37.93 |                                                                                                                                
  freightQuoteAssistant.js                     |   37.93 |    18.18 |   26.67 |   37.93 | 51-57,67-150                                                                                                                   
 jobMonitor                                    |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                                                                                                                                
  jobMonitor.js                                |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 5-104
```

Why are many LWC classes/tests now missing from the coverage run??  This used to show all of them.

From package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage"
  },
```

Thanks for your help!

Adding jest.config.js:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    // add any custom configurations here
};
```

Comment: what version of lwc-jest and sfdx cli are you using?

Comment: sfdx-cli/7.113.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.4

Comment: "jest": "^27.0.6",

Comment: I am also noticing that it executes all the tests too quickly -- it appears to be marking tests as successful without running them.   It used to take much longer to run npm run test:unit:coverage when all the tests where correctly displayed in the coverage table.

Comment: If you check your `jest.config.js` and look at `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` does it include anything that might match those that are missing?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kris.  Added jest.config.js to the post.  Nothing I can see there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting and recreating my project in VSCode.  Fixed the problem but not sure why...